# Give regular expression for the set of strings over $\{a,b,c\}$ with length AT MOST 3

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I would just like to confirm the regular expression which I have is correct.

$(\epsilon+a+b+c)*(\epsilon+a+b+c)*(\epsilon+a+b+c)$

Would this be the correct regexp for a set of strings $\{a,b,c\}$ with length AT MOST 3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe your regular expression is correct.  If you're allowed to use the $\ \{n\}\ $ operator, a more compact way of writing it would be
$$
\left(\epsilon+a+b+c\right)\{3\}
$$

Comment: The $\{n\}$ operator is not a standard mathematical operator. I would not recommend for it here on math.stackexchange.

Comment: I was attempting to guess the notation that would be most likely to be familiar to the OP, and took the expression "$\{n\}$" from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts).  Nevertheless, since the subject is one that lies within your fields of expertise, and not one that I can claim much more than a nodding acquaintance with, I shall follow your recommendation in the future (unless I have some good reason not to) and I'd advise the OP to do the same.

Comment: Let me clarify: my recommendation is for a mathematical notation to be used in formal language theory. If you are discussing with a Perl programmer, this would be another story.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is coorect. If $A = \{a,b,c\}$ is the alphabet, you could also write it as $(1 + A)^3$ or as $1 + A + A^2 + A^3$.